# NSXMLParser : foundcharacters get < > element and break

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsstring, nsxmlparser

My XML :

```
<root>
<row>
<name>ABC</name>
<contacts> C1 <abc@abc.com> C2 <xyz@xyz.com> </contacts>
</row>
<root>
```

When i start parsing

It will be break after **C1** string. Coz it got **<** element. and give me error like here,

> parser error : Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=68 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 68.)"
>   UserInfo=0x143e3ba0 {NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber=1,
>   NSXMLParserErrorColumn=966, NSXMLParserErrorMessage=error parsing
>   attribute name }

The question seems be easy, But its not.
Please response with your best solution.

Comment: It must be handled on server-side. The data in the contact node can be CDATA or URLEncoded. If not, the only way you can do on client-side is to make your own parser with string manipulating methods.

Comment: Thanks, I have try with string manipulating methods, But its dynamic <contacts>block so not judge <email> string. Do you have any idea how to do please respond too.